# $\int_{0}^{1} x \ dx$ without fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: integration, limits, analysis, summation

How can one calculate $\int_{0}^{1} x \ dx$ without the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Can I do something like this?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

$$\int_0^1x \ dx=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{n^2}\sum_{r=1}^nr$$

$$\text{And then }\sum_{r=1}^nr=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

Then maybe $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(n+1)}2$

But then? Is that approach even correct?

Comment: So you should have factored out $1/n^2$, and otherwise you have the right idea.

Comment: The first displayed equation is only true if $f$ is known to have an integral on $[0,1]$; otherwise, the limit on the left-hand side might exist while the integral on the right does not.  In this case, you know that the integral exists because the function is continuous (assuming that you know that theorem).  Then you can proceed as you have, with the suggestion from @Ian.

Comment: You forgot a $1/n^{2}$ term in the limit. The ideia seems nice. Another approach would be calculating the area of the right triangle with sides $l_{1} = l_{2} =1$ and $l_{3} = \sqrt{2}$ if you interpret the integral as the "area beneath the curve"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, area to sum is simply a right triangle with base $1$ and height $1$. This gives us $\text{Area}=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \text{Base}\cdot \text{Height}=\dfrac{1}{2}$. However, given that this has tags like "summation" and "limits," I expect that you need to calculate the area using a type of Riemann Sum.

With your approach, you are almost there. Once you have $$\int_0^1 x\,\text{d}x = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\cdot\sum_{r=1}^n r\right)=  \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\cdot\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right),$$you just need to evaluate that final limit. Note that you cannot evaluate the limits of the factors separately, because this would result in an indeterminate form $0\cdot \infty$. However, this limit simplifies nicely:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\cdot\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}.$$